# Find the Taylor series at $a=\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $f(x)=x\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to find the taylor series at $a = \frac{\pi}{2}$ for $f(x)=x\sin(x)$

The problem is that I don't know if my answer is right..

Could somebody check/correct this

$f(x) = x\sin(x)$

let $x = t+\frac{\pi}{2}$

so that $f(t+\frac{\pi}{2})=(t+\frac{\pi}{2})\sin(t+\frac{\pi}{2})$

which gives $f(t+\frac{\pi}{2})=(t+\frac{\pi}{2})\cos(t)$

Now find the Maclaurin series which I ended up with

$x\left(1-\frac{\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2}{2!}+\frac{\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^4}{4!}-\frac{\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^6}{6!}+\ldots\right)$

Comment: If your goal is to have a formula for the coefficients of powers, then you haven't received it yet.

Comment: How can I got further than this with my question? I'm not quite understanding what I can do more.

Comment: I think if you wanted to proceed in this fashion you could rewrite as $f(t + \frac{\pi}2) = t\cos(t) + \frac{\pi}2 \cos t,$ so $f(x) = (x - \frac{\pi}2)\cos(x-\frac{\pi}2) + \frac{\pi}2 \cos t.$ Using the Maclaurin series for $\cos$ and manipulating the series should give you what you need.

Comment: Look separately at the coefficients of odd and even powers. You would notice some patterns.

Comment: I suppose answer must contain only powers of $\left(x-\frac{\pi}2\right)$, so one needs to express $x$ factor as $\left(x-\frac{\pi}2\right)+\frac{\pi}2$ and expand with it.